# Stop element from scrolling past certain point in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm currently building a scrolling share bar for this dev website: http://ossian.statenews.com/~matt/statenews-redesign-1.1/docs/article.html

How do I make jQuery look for the "related-stories" div class and stop it from scrolling past?

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $sidebar   = $("#sharebox"),
$window    = $(window),
offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
topPadding = 50;

$window.scroll(function() {
if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
$sidebar.stop().animate({
marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
});
} else {
$sidebar.stop().animate({
marginTop: 0 

});
}
});
});
```

Comment: right, I have the div class in place. I'm wondering how I would target that in jQuery and how to make it stop scrolling there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you just want the scrolling share bar to "stick" to the related stories once you scroll down that low. You are already half way there. the same way you don't start the share bar from scrolling at the beginning is similar to how you will stop it at the end.

You just need to determine the case of when you want to freeze the scrolling share.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $sidebar   = $("#sharebox"),
      $window    = $(window),
      offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
      topPadding = 50;

  $window.scroll(function() {
    if($window.scrollTop() > $('.related-stories').offset().top) {
      // basically this is just saying, that if you've scrolled passed the related
      // stories, we are going to force you back in line with them.
      // Edit: This needs to be first because the "else if" case is always true when
      //       this would be true so it never actually fails and calls this code.
      $sidebar.stop().css('marginTop', $('.related-stories').offset().top);
    } else if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
      $sidebar.stop().animate({
        marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
      });
    } else {
      $sidebar.stop().animate({
        marginTop: 0 
      });
    }
  });
});
```

This should solve the problem for you. The code might be a little off and you may need to play with it a bit. I'll check again if you have any follow up questions but that won't be until this evening. Good luck!

Comment: I'll take a look and hack away at it, but the way you described it makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: Hm, it's still scrolling past the object I defined. I tried changing classes/IDs as well and still nothing.

Comment: First thing that is obvious to me is that you now have a javascript error on the page. Line 18 of smooth-scroll.js, looks like the real problem is on line 16. I think `$target` should be `$(this).hash` not `$(this.hash)`

Comment: The smooth scroll is connect to the "comment' anchor tag that scrolls down to the comment box. When I changed this is stopped working, I'll figure out what's throwing that error. The JS file that's connected to the share box is "share.js"

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out. I had a bug, basically the way it was written before the first `if` case we were testing would always be true when the second case (where you want to stop it from scrolling) would be true. So it would never fail causing the program to go to the `else if`. I've edited my code.

Comment: I'm trying this out and have one small issue.  It's extending the parents height.  I can't explicitly set height for the parent because there's dynamic content being loaded in.   Basically I'd like the sliding div to stop when it reaches the #footer div.  Any recommendations ?